# How can I play all audios form list using assets_audio_player in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, web-audio-api, audio-player

I'm fetching audio URLs from Web API and store them into List and apply **assets_audio_player** it will only play audio at first index. I use for loop for it but this doesn't' work. How can I handle this issue?

Here is the method to fetch the audio URL, In this method, I've implemented for loop for players to play audio at each Index.

```
List<String> surahAudioList = [];

  Future getAudioData() async {
    String url = 'http://api.quran.com/api/v3/chapters/${widget.surahIndex}/verses?recitation=1&page=1&limit=16&text_type=words';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    List<dynamic> data = map['verses'];
    if (surahAudioList.length != 0) surahAudioList.clear();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      surahAudioList.add('https://audio.qurancdn.com/${data[i]['audio']["url"]}');

      _assetsAudioPlayer.open(Playlist(audios: [Audio.network(surahAudioList[i], metas: Metas(title: 'Song1', artist: 'Artist'))]), showNotification: true, autoStart: false);
    }

    print(surahAudioList);
  }
```

these methods help to play and pause audio.

```
  playMusic() async {
    await _assetsAudioPlayer.play();
  }

  pauseMusic() async {
    await _assetsAudioPlayer.pause();
  }

IconButton(
 onPressed: () => isPlaying ? pauseMusic() : playMusic(),
 icon: Icon(isPlaying ? Icons.pause_circle_filled : Icons.play_circle_fill),),
```

Comment: you want to play multiple audio at same time on click of a single button?

Comment: @Vettiyanakan yes sir and also wants to play audio of each index but every time it only plays audio at index 0.

Comment: @UsamaHafeez were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
assetsAudioPlayer.open(
  Playlist(
    audios: [
      Audio("assets/audios/song1.mp3"), // replace with your urls
      Audio("assets/audios/song2.mp3")
    ]
  ),
  loopMode: LoopMode.playlist //loop the full playlist
);

assetsAudioPlayer.next();
assetsAudioPlayer.prev();
assetsAudioPlayer.playlistPlayAtIndex(1);
```

refer to this code.
In you `for loop` you add the files to `PlayList` Object. then play it separately.

```
assetsAudioPlayer.playlistPlayAtIndex(1);
```

You have to specify the index to play the audio.

Happy coding!

Comment: It still playing 0 index audio, I have multiple numbers of audio fetched from the server. I placed URL where you asked

Comment: use the .playlistPlayAtIndex( index of file );